# Upgrading from 0.7 to 0.9: how do I access my event's keypath?

Tags: ractivejs

https://jsfiddle.net/zFiddler/gm9k4mrc/1/

Given this:

```
var view = new Ractive({
    el : '#container',
    template : "{{#item}}<a href='#' on-click='doSomething'>Do Something</a>{{/}}",
    data : {item : {name: "item"}}
})

view.on('doSomething', event => {
event.original.preventDefault();
console.log(event);
alert(event.keypath);
});
```

How would I access the keypath for the fired event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 0.9, in jQuery-esque fashion, and to be consistent between component and element events, handlers attached via [`ractive.on`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractiveon) will now receive an instance of the [Context](https://ractive.js.org/api/#context-object) object as first argument which should contain everything you need to know about the event, the node it's from, the Ractive instance attached to it, and so on. DOM events should be available via the [`event`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#contextevent) property of that object (no longer the funny-sounding `original`). The keypath can be obtained by [`context.resolve()`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#contextresolve).

```
view.on('doSomething', context => {
  const event = context.event
  event.original.preventDefault();
  console.log(event);
  alert(context.resolve());
});
```

Comment: This makes me think the docs at https://ractive.js.org/api/#on-42 are misleading as the first arg is always named "event" and not "context"

Comment: @NickWiltshire yep, a PR was made recently to fix something similar. I guess there's more of them. D: